# Jetty 9 XML Connector Configuration error

Tags: jetty-9

I am attempting to run jetty 9.3.8.  I had to change over my Jetty 8 configuration, which was working, but I am now receiving a `Config error` which prints out the whole XML connector configuration line.

Here is what Jetty doesn't like - `jetty.xml`

```
<Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelecChannelConnector">
           <Set name="host">
              <Property name="jetty.host" default="localhost"/>
           </Set>
           <Set name="port">
              <Property name="jetty.port" default="7080"/>
           </Set>
           <Set name="maxIdleTime">60000</Set>
           <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
           <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
           <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
           <Set name="confidentialPort">7443</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

Any ideas are great.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `SelecChannelConnector` => `SelectChannelConnector`.

Anyway, for Jetty 9 you should prefer the use of `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector` as quoted in Jetty's own documentation:

> Prior to Jetty 9, the type of the connector specified both the protocol and the implementation used; for example, selector-based non blocking I/O vs blocking I/O, or SSL connector vs non-SSL connector. Jetty 9 has a single selector-based non-blocking I/O connector, and a collection of ConnectionFactories now configure the protocol on the connector.

[Configuring Jetty Connectors](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html)